# Convert 2025 bits to shortest filename

Tags: php

I have some information represented by 2025 bits. For caching purposes i need to create a unique filename ( not too long of course so fs will handle this ) which will represent these bits. Every set of bits should have unique filename.

Is md5 suitable for this ? If not , what should i use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid).  If you are ultra paranoid, put the filename generation in a loop where you check to see if it exists or not.

```
$prefix   = hash('sha256', $bits) . '-';
$filename = uniqid($prefix, true);
```

This creates a SHA-256 hash of the bits as the prefix to the file, and uses `uniqid` to create a unique file name with the prefix of the file being the hash of the bits followed by a `-`.

This should generate a unique filename that you can identify by hashing the bits.

Comment: for caching purposes i need to have the exactly unique the same filename from those bits.

Comment: Is it possible for the same sequence of bits to be generated twice?

Comment: Sequence of bits can be generated twice , every time they need to create exactly the same filename.

Comment: I see, then perhaps SHA-256 is a long enough has to be sufficient.  The `uniqid()` makes sure to generate a unique file using the hash of the bits as the prefix of the file.  Remove the `uniqid` call if you need the filename to be identical for the same set of bits each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of the bits. This will guarantee uniqueness of names.

Comment: base64 will output larger filename than the bits converted to string

Comment: What? How is a 7 digit bit string shorter than a 1 digit Base64 encoded string?

Comment: how to create 7 digit bit string from 2025 bits ie. $bits = "111000000000000000100000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...."

Comment: @PawełPlewa: 4AAgAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...

Comment: will this output be shorter than 2025 chars ? if you do base64_encode($2025_length_string) you will get ~2700 length string

Comment: That's because `base64_encode()` treats the argument as an input string, not as a binary string. If you want to use that function, you'll have to do an string encoding first.

Comment: base64 encoding includes '/' which is a directory separator on linux & Mac